# SMS Verification Code to user Phone Number

Tags: php, mobile, sms-gateway

What can I do to verify that the mobile phone number on the registration form?

User: Website RegisterForm > Enter the telephone number > Phone confirmation code > Membership Ok!

How is this done?

Comment: What do you mean by "phone confirmation code"? Do you mean sending an SMS to the phone number?

Comment: Yes SMS, verification code to phone number

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't give much information on what technologies you're using, so there might be a better tailored solution for your case, but you'll need to generate your access code (ideally using a secure random generator), configure your backend to access a SMS Webservice like [Esendex](http://www.esendex.com) (please note, it's not free), send the code through it and then validate that the code the user inputs is exactly the one you've generated.

[Here](http://www.esendex.co.uk/Developers/SDKs/PHP-SMS-SDK) you can find a link to their SMS PHP SDK.

Comment: I am using PHP. I do not know how to set up a connection with Esendex. Sample test codes or via my site would be good to test. (sorry for Eng) Thank you for your interest!

Answer (score 2):

Consider using [Twillio](http://www.twilio.com/). They have an API to handle SMS and phone transactions. You can call the API from within PHP, and their rates are like 1 cent per text or less.

Comment: how to use the API then ?

Comment: @RajuGujarati If you go to the Twillio.com website you can see code examples. Basically you sign up for an account and then use their REST API to send SMS messages. Here is a link to some sample PHP code: http://www.twilio.com/docs/quickstart/php/sms/sending-via-rest