# Can I verify a phone number with aws amplify before updating the user?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-amplify

For example if an existing user wants to change the phone number to get MFA codes, I would like to verify the phone number before updating the user.

Is that possible?

Comment: What do you mean by "verify" a phone number? As in if it is a valid, working number?

Comment: Send a code to that user uses to validate the phone number in a popup dialog so that when we update the users account in Cognito we have the correct number. Otherwise if MFA is enabled and for some reason he/she logouts, login won't work as the MFA code is sent to the wrong number. My guess is that you first update the user in Cognito then you validate.

Comment: Ooooh ok. There are actually a few API's that can help with this. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9363346/sms-verification-code-to-user-phone-number

Comment: It's fine I think I will just show a dialog after phone was updated and send a code + force people to confirm on every change.